Dumb question about OSPF with router-on-a-stick
Suppose that we have several sites connected using fiber Ethernet, with each site having its own router. But due to certain requirements1, the routers cannot be connected point-to-point directly – instead, the fiber connections are between Ethernet switches, with all of the routers hanging off (one or two) trunk ports on those switches.

(Sorry, I don't have PacketTracer for the diagram.)
In this situation, is it better (mainly for the purposes of using OSPF) to:

create multiple VLANs to imitate point-to-point links between routers (e.g. R1—R2, R4—R5, …) so that OSPF would be aware of link costs and such?

or create a single 'backbone' VLAN that contains all routers, so that traffic between sites (e.g. R1—R5) could take a more direct path via Ethernet without going through R1 (or R4)?



1 (In reality this is mainly because there is a Wi-Fi "captive portal" system which those routers cannot handle, so the respective VLANs from all sites have to be trunked to a central place where the gateway for said system is located. Maybe that's a problem in itself but it is outside the scope of the question.)

Would you create a point-to-point link between every pair of routers or just some of them?

Only between those routers whose sites have the physical connections, e.g. R1-R3 but not R2-R3. (That is, only those pairs which would "normally" have point-to-point links were it not for the L2 switching requirement.)

If that's all the topology there is, ie. no redundant links, then it doesn't matter whether you use multiple VLANs or just one.
A single VLAN has the advantage of simplifying the adjacency setup by just using multicast.
Regarding your comment to Ron's answer: I don't necessarily mean VLANs between all pairs of routers – only between those sites which actually have a direct Ethernet connection in the first place, so e.g. between R1-R2 and R1-R3 but not R2-R3.:
In your diagram, all routers are adjacent on Ethernet's data link layer (same segment, broadcast domain and subnet). Traffic between R2 and R3 is switched on the Site 1 switch, not forwarded across R1. If you use VLANs to separate them, then R1 needs to be used for forwarding, resulting in one extra L3 and two extra L2 hops.

In this case yes, there are no redundant links, but would the answer be different if e.g. R3-R4 had a slower backup link?

@grawity, in a single OSPF area, each router has a complete understanding of the area, including all other routers and the costs to reach them.

You could actually create trunk links with VLANs that would allow each router to have a point-to-point link with every other router, but that does not really scale. There is a formula for figuring the number of connections:
      (n x (n - 1)) / 2 so (5 x 4) / 2 = 10

So it would require 10 separate VLANs for just the router point-to-point connections for five routers. Adding a router would require five more VLANs, and adding another six more VLANs, etc. This is the same problem with iBGP, and it is the reason iBGP can have route reflectors.
By creating a single "router connection" VLAN, OSPF can have a single area where the routers directly connect to each other (ethernet is broadcast). At the start, they will elect a DR and BDR to solve the scale problem of direct links in order to share routing information, but sending traffic will go directly from one router to another router in that VLAN.

Ah, I don't necessarily mean VLANs between all pairs of routers – only between those sites which actually have a direct Ethernet connection in the first place, so e.g. between R1-R2 and R1-R3 but not R2-R3. Sorry if the diagram is unclear. (Though my example is extremely unlikely to grow larger than the current amount of sites, so a full mesh might be a third option anyway.)

If all the switches for the routers are connected as you show, I would just create a single VLAN for the router connections, making sure that your Site 1 in the diagram is the root bridge for that VLAN (else you can create other problems) by making it the lowest priority bridge and not depending on the MAC addressing of the switches to decide the root.

If you create a separate VLAN for each pair of directly connected sites, the packets will follow paths determined by the routers according to OSPF and IP headers. If site 1 sends a packet to site 5, it will pass through router 1, switch 1, switch 4, router 4, switch 4, switch 5, and router 5. OSPF can use all links. For example, if sites 3 and 5 were connected later, traffic could flow directly between sites 3 and 5 without passing through sites 1 and 4. Each router knows the other routers connected to it because they are configured on it.
If you create a single VLAN for the whole arrangement, the packets will follow paths determined by the switches alone according to Ethernet alone. In the depicted network there is only one possible path between any two points. If there was more than one path, redundant paths would be blocked with a protocol such as RSTP until there was only one. For example, if sites 3 and 5 were connected later, RSTP might decide to disable this link until one of the other links breaks and this link is needed to keep the network connected together, and then it will enable it. Each router automatically discovers the other routers by broadcasting packets, which makes the network easier to configure.
